# Problem accessing variable[] from another class

Tags: java

I know this a pretty basic question, and already found another ones like mine, but I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public int teste;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

    }

    public int getTest()
    {
        return teste;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        teste = 2;
....
}
}
```

and other class:

```
try{

                InteractiveArrayAdapter adapt = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
            getAPPS(0));
                int test = adapt.getTest();
                Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(test), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v("TAG",Integer.toString(test));
            }catch(Exception e)
                {
                Log.v("EXCEPTION",e.toString());
            }
```

EDIT:  I was getting null for a stupid mistake, and now I'm getting the primitive and expected 0 as most of you say.

At some point of my app, everytime a checkboxes is clicked that method getView is executed. I want to store that to an array[] of strings progressively (i+1) (i just put int to be easier to understand - realize now it was a mistake), and then when users inputs ok I want to access the whole array. Wondering if it's possible the way I want.

So when I do this

```
InteractiveArrayAdapter adapt = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
                getAPPS(0));
```

This is meaningless, because I don't need to execute anything again, I just want to retrieve the created array - if possible!

Comment: Did you initialize "this.teste" to a non-null value?

Comment: As written here, it's impossible for `getTest()` to return `null`. The method is declared as returning a primitive `int`.

Comment: is this a real question?

Comment: @Alan Moore: It automatically happens. Whenever the object is constructed `test` is implicitly initialized to 0.

Comment: Please don't downvote... I said I know it's a basic question, and it's a problem.

Comment: @Tiago Your question, in its current state, is not a good question.  You didn't copy/paste so the code sample does not reflect your actual code, and the problem you describe "getTest returns a null value" is impossible.  Given these problems, it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @Tiago, it's note being downvoted because it's basic. It's that the code provided in the question doesn't illustrate the problem correctly. Therefore any answers are guesses at best. As normalocity says below, just copy/paste the essential stuff -- we can handle it.

Comment: Remove the try/catch and run the program.

Comment: @Tiago as an aside, `teste` should be private.

Comment: Ah, much better. Now another question. Which line of the code causes the NPE. In fact, the stack trace would be even better.

Comment: I agree, I hope it's better now. @Farray I'll change to private and keep the getter then.

Comment: After all there's no need for a stacktrace. Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But that is what should happen according to your code. You don't call B method to update teste variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't even compile. `return this.teste;` should be `return this.test;`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake making the question (I didn't make copy paste).

Answer (score 2):

Well, this isn't a direct copy/paste, since this obviously wouldn't compile. Whenever you're dealing with an actual error or issue, it's really best to paste the actual code. We're all programmers, so we can read it.

But based on the structure you've shown above, either the typo you've put in the line `return this.teste` (should be `return this.test`) is in your code, or you didn't initialize the instance variable `test` in your constructor.

Without showing us the actual code you're writing, it's impossible to say (especially the section that initializes the `test` variable, and the part that returns its value are missing - we're not mind readers, I'm afraid).

So, those are two potential candidates. On another note, however, if you mark the `test` variable as public, then you don't need to have getter/setter methods for them, since any class can access them without going through a method call. That's what public does.